# Iteration in asp.net databinding

Tags: c#, asp.net

Say I have an array like so in my code behind:

public static string[] fields = new string[]{"field1", "field2", "field3", "field4"};

I would like to use this array to retrieve fields in a gridview when it is databinding, like so:

```
<%# Eval("Field1")%>
<%# Eval("Field2")%>
<%# Eval("Field3")%>
<%# Eval("Field4")%>
```

However, I have had a very difficult time figuring out how to iterate over my array (fields) to produce the above code. It does not want to parse any operators within the databinding server tags (<%# %>) like so:

```
<%# foreach (string field in fields)
    {
       Eval(field);
    }
%>
```

And I cannot find a way to reproduce the databinding behavior in regular server tags:

```
<% foreach (string field in fields)
    {
       Response.Write(DataBinder.Eval(object, field);
    }
%>
```

The databinder.eval method takes a container object which I'm not sure I can access outside of the regular databinding tags. I have also tried using regular server tags to produce the iteration code surrounding the databinding code, but it is not able to access the variables of the iteration.

**EDIT:**

I should be more clear, in the end I want the values to end up on my page, not the field names themselves. My database might look something like:

```
Field1 | Field2 | Field3 | Field4
       |        |        |
value1 | value2 | value3 | value4
```

and when is all said and done, my page should look like:

```
value1
value2
value3
value4
```

BUT the fields array is dynamic, and may be different depending on the object, so statically accessing each index in the array won't work.

Comment: I completely misunderstood the question, d'oh! (And it looks like I'm not the only one.) So you want to choose which fields are bound to another databound control dynamically? In other words, you want your other control to bind to fields 1-4 now, but you'd like to be able to change to fields 5-8 at the drop of a hat?

Comment: Essentially. There is a level of abstraction in the object in the program that is getting represented here, so I want to reflect that abstraction here. For example one object could decide to use field1, field2, and field3, and another could decide to use field5 and field6. This is I think what you've said, the only difference is that you mention 1-4 and 5-8, which are the same number of fields, in which case I could write Eval(fields[0]), Eval(fields[1]), etc.. It will be a variable size, though.

Comment: So how are you determining which rows display which fields?

Comment: it is a section of the results I want to iterate over which fall into a logical category. The results returned have the concepts of "events" and I want to output the even name and whether or not it has occured. However, the object itself is abstract, and only contains a list of events (which contain their corresponding sql field). I want to iterate over this to check the status of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a solution that I've patched together from the responses I've gotten so far.

The trick was to pass the container instance to a static method so I could do my iteration. The raw databinding server controls (<%# %>) don't allow for operators, but you may simply pass the container to a static method to do so.

**Markup:**

```
<%# GetItems(Container) %>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected static string GetItems(IDataItemContainer container)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string[] StaticSQLFields = MyStaticClass.StaticSQLFields;
    for (int i = 0; i < StaticSQLFields.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(DataBinder.Eval(container.DataItem, StaticSQLFields[i]) + "<br>");
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on EDIT:

**Markup:**

```
<asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server">  
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# GetIndexedItem(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem)) %>
        <!--or--->
        <%# GetIndexedItem(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem), 0) %>
        <%# GetIndexedItem(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem), 1) %>
        <%# GetIndexedItem(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem), 2) %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
void Page_Load(Object Sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (!IsPostBack) 
  {         
     Repeater1.DataSource = fields ;
     Repeater1.DataBind();    

  }
}

protected string GetIndexedItem(object obj, int idx)
{
    //add some array bounds checking..etc
    //if you need to loop through the array and return something
    //you can do that here instead of getting by index
    return obj[idx].ToString();       

}

protected string GetIndexedItem(object obj)
{ 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string[] lst = (string[])obj;
    for(int i=0;i<lst.Length; i++)
    {
        //something like this
        sb.Append(lst[i].ToString() + "<br>" )
    }
    return sb.ToString() ;       

}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on the nested object graph part? The soluton you present doesn't solve my problem, it merely outputs the strings of the fields themselves.

Comment: Oh, and it's important that the array size can change :) I'll throw that in the edit as well.